# Use memcached symfony/windows

Tags: php, windows, symfony, memcached

Hello all :) I need some help :) let's explain my problem

The last week i tried to install memcached (with a D) on windows and symfony php project.
The fact is that for memcache all is ok but after multiple tries to install memcached i am still stuck.

I don't know how to use the memcached and call it with php :

```
memcached = new Memcached(); //Error can't load class Memcached
memcache = new Memcache();   //It's ok i can use it
```

And the pain is that i only need the functionality from memcached:

```
memcached->getResultCode()
```

getResultCode() exist in memcached but not in memcache :'(

Somebody have the same issue ? i tried all the tutorials to install memcached and always i can't load the memcached class ...

Many thanks in advance this issue is really annoying for my project :(

Best regards,
CUETO Vincent

Comment: So, is `memcached` extension loaded? `phpinfo()`?

Comment: Hi zerkms :) No i checked this and i have only memcache loaded in the phpinfo() i did a memcached -d start in console to run it and memcached is corectly launched but well .. i can't even load the class

Comment: So, install a php `memcached` extension then? " and memcached is corectly launched but well" --- `memcached` daemon has nothing to do with php `memcached` extension.

Comment: what you mean with extension ? a bundle ?

Comment: I mean php extension: http://php.net/memcached

Comment: Yes but with windows there is no sudo install ^^ there is no tar.gz what can i do :s

Comment: I have no idea, I don't (and probably no one at all) use windows for serving php apps

Comment: Well they could do something just to test it on windows ... my prod server is on linux but not my dev app ... well thanks

Comment: I see no reason to even test something in a different environment. With Vagrant+Virtualbox it takes several minutes to get nearly-production configuration on your windows desktop.

Comment: Just cause it's my environment ... i built all my project on it but ok i will continue my work without cache for the moment